# PATH variable in different terminal windows

Tags: environment-variables, bashrc, console, paths, source

I note that if I have several terminal windows opened and in one of them I set path variable through bashrc:

```
export APP_PATH="path_to_app"    
export PATH="$APP_PATH:$PATH"
```

Then call:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then new path is visible only in that window where I did it. Why? How can I make it visible to others?

More of that if I call source several times all of the path entries are duplicated. Again why? I thought source just reloads all information for bashrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `source ~/.bashrc` you reload your `~/.bashrc` configuration only for that current terminal session. You have to do it for all other existing terminal sessions as well if you want to reload your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: And what about the whole system?

Comment: If you open a new terminal it will read from the `~/.bashrc` configuration file. Do mind that `bashrc` is a user dependet file. If you for example open up a terminal as root you will load your `bashrc` from `/root/.bashrc`.